# IOS11 UIContextualAction Place the image color text

Tags: objective-c, ios11

To prevent the picture How to restore the real color I now place the image are white

```
- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0))
{

 UIContextualAction *deleteRowAction = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleNormal title:nil handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL))
    {
        NSLog(@"------------------>%@",sourceView);
        completionHandler (YES);
    }];

    deleteRowAction.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heart"];

    UISwipeActionsConfiguration *config = [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:@[deleteRowAction]];
         return config;


    return nil;

}
```

Answer (score 15):

RSSReaderMaker solution work with small updates Swift 5:

```
class ImageWithoutRender: UIImage {
    override func withRenderingMode(_ renderingMode: UIImage.RenderingMode) -> UIImage {
        return self
    }
}
```

And in `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`  or `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`

Use:

```
if let cgImageX =  UIImage(named: "x_blue_big")?.cgImage {
     action.image = ImageWithoutRender(cgImage: cgImageX, scale: UIScreen.main.nativeScale, orientation: .up)
}
```

Comment: Genius. Can someone maybe explain why this works? Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: I don't seem to need the custom class in iOS 14.3, which only seem to return the rendering mode of the asset itself?

Answer (score 6):

You can change the color of the image by modifying the general `tintColor` of `UIImage` via `UIAppearance`, for example like this:

`UIImageView.appearance().tintColor = .yellow`

but this applies that (default) tint color to all image views in your app, so you might limit it to image views within a table view by setting it this way:

`UIImageView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableView.self]).tintColor = .yellow`

You can also specify your own `UITableView` subclass if you have one.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem.
The first step is to declare a subclass of UIImage with a random name and override its imageWithRenderingMode: method.
I want to do this

```
@implementation FakeImage

- (UIImage *)imageWithRenderingMode:(UIImageRenderingMode)renderingMode
{
     return self;
}
@end
```

The second step, when assigning values to UIContextualAction, use this class, pay attention to instantiate with initWithCGImage method.

```
UIContextualAction* action = xxxx;
action.image = [[FakeImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zoo_icon_time"].CGImage scale:2 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Get it done.

Comment: This solution is half worked for me, it will also change the size of the image.

Comment: I guess there was a problem with the step of regenerating the UIImage, try trying to adjust the scale parameter.
[[FakeImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zoo_icon_time"].CGImage scale:*2（here）* orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, but watch out for that scale.

Answer (score 2):

`trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath` works from iOS 11 only and is completely not customizable. You can change background color of a button, but you cannot add an image with you own colors even if you use `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`.

I recommend using `MGSwipeTableCell`.