# Image in TableViewCell swipe action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

I have a swipe action to 'complete' a task in my to-do list app. This is the image I have set:

[image]

However when the cell is swiped, the image looks like this:

[image: Swiped image]

Is there a way to make the background transparent/white and the image to have the green circle like the image above?

If there is not, is there a way to make the green background 'wrap' to the purple of the cell so there is no whitespace?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second image, the green is the UIContextualAction's `backgroundColor` and the white is the `tintColor`.

The image is treated as a template image — that is, its colors are ignored, and instead it is drawn transparent where your image is transparent, and drawn opaque with the `tintColor` where your image is opaque.

So, basically you would need to reverse your settings: set the background color to white and change the tint color to the darker green shown in your image. Setting the tint color is not easy, but you could do it, for example, in your app delegate `didFinishLaunching` using the appearance proxy, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51422830/341994) (though this may have other unwanted side effects):

```
UIImageView.appearance(
    whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableView.self])
        .tintColor = // whatever that green is
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work? I put what you wrote into my AppDelegate.swift but nothing changed. This is the function:
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UIImageView.appearance(
            whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableView.self])
            .tintColor = .yellow // whatever that green is
    }

Comment: The app delegate method is called `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`. You don't have to add it; it's already there.

Comment: No worries - sorry Apple didn't provide a real way to do this, you might file an enhancement request.

Answer (score 9):

In came up with this extension for UIImage:

```
    extension UIImage {
        func colored(in color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
            return renderer.image { context in
                color.set()
                self.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate).draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
            }
        }
    }
```

It returns a new icon in the new color when used like this:

```
        swipAction.image = UIImage(named: "myImage")?.colored(in: .white)
```

Maybe this helps someone.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Can be applied to UIAction icons in UIMenu. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 13 with SF Symbol, simply use UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal to change the symbol color.

```
replyAction.image = [[UIImage systemImageNamed: @"arrowshape.turn.up.left.circle.fill"] imageWithTintColor: self.view.tintColor renderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Comment: In iOS 13, one could simply use `action.image = someImage.withTintColor(.green, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)`