# Changing tint color of system image in trailing swipe action

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, uiimage, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

I'm trying to change color of trash system image but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { (ac: UIContextualAction, view: UIView, success: (Bool) -> Void) in
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? HeroTableViewCell
        if let _ = cell?.nameLabel.text {
            self.deleteHeroName(index: indexPath)
        }
        success(true)
    }
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash")?.withTintColor(.red)
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}
```

I need it because I'm trying to give clear background to my delete action and image color is white.

Comment: Why didn't you use the `ac.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash")?.withTintColor(.red)` in deleteAction closure?

Comment: If I do it like that image doesn't show

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582080/image-in-tableviewcell-swipe-action)

Answer (score 1):

For me adding rendering mode as `.alwaysOriginal` (**note**, not `.alwaysTemplate` as we would usually use for tinting an image) worked:

```swift
action.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash")?.withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
```