# Change text size of UIContextualAction

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

How can I increase the size of text at my `UIContextualAction`? Here is how I set it up.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "\u{02606}", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        success(true)
    })
    action.backgroundColor = .blue
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action]) 
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you can't change the font size of an UIContextualAction titleLabel

Comment: You could mess around with `UIAppearance`, but this will always be an unreliable hack, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398910/ios11-uicontextualaction-place-the-image-color-text

Comment: This solution works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588715/set-custom-font-for-uitableview-swipe-action-uicontextualaction