# Set properly a colored icon in UIContextualAction

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicontextualaction, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

I am using a TableView to list some images with descriptions. Additionally this images needs to be shared and deleted and theirfore I am using `UIContextualAction`. To the object I set the image for deleting like this:

`deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete")`

Unfortunately in runtime I can see my image is colored white, but I need it grey. Why is this behaviour?

Comment: Here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55706586/4427884

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS11 UIContextualAction Place the image color text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398910/ios11-uicontextualaction-place-the-image-color-text)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think it will help.
[image]